# power bi - ranking on a date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I tried to make a ranking on a date so that every beginning of a month it resets but I can't get it. the furthest I got is that every month simply gets an cumulative ranking based on RANKX on power bi which includes a month and a year.
Has anyone needed such a ranking and succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

A generalised set-up for a **Calculated Column** would be along the lines of:

```
=
VAR ThisMonth =
    MONTH( Table1[Date] )
RETURN
    RANKX(
        FILTER( Table1, MONTH( Table1[Date] ) = ThisMonth ),
        Table1[Date],
        ,
        ASC
    )
```